# Remove items in drop-down list based on items selected in other drop down lists

Tags: c#, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a number of drop-down lists holding usernames. Each ddl is generated from the same model (They hold the same information).

However, each user should only be selected once within this form. Is there a way to check which users have been selected and stop them from appearing in the drop-down lists, and then re-appear again if the value is removed from a dll.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="modalbox" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id="modal-header" class="modal-header">
                    <h1>Register New Booking</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="booking-model-table" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Person1:</td>
                            <td>
                                @{
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idP1" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserText)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Person2:</td>
                            <td>
                                @{
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idP2" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserText)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Person3:</td>
                            <td>
                                @{
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idP3" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserText)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Person4:</td>
                            <td>
                                @{
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "idP4" })
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserText)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Ok</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                                    }
```

**Model**

```
/// <summary>
/// User List
/// </summary>
[Display(Name = "Users")]
public string User { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }
public string SelectedUserText { get; set; }
```

Would this be possible? I was thinking of adding some javascript to remove the item within an onchange event, but as each ddl runs off the same model I'd imagine it would delete the response.

**Update:**
I found a possible solution which works for me at the moment, using Javascript and adding the seat-select value to each drop-down.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { @class = "form-control seat-select", @id = "idP1", @onchange = "cleanUsers(this);"
```

The Javascript file:

```
function cleanUsers(ddl) {
var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
var vOldVal =   $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected");
                $("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected", val);

//If a user is selected disable them
if (val != 0) { $(".seat-select option[value='" + val + "']").attr("disabled", true); }

//If the previous value has been defined, enable the user again 
if (vOldVal != undefined) { $(".seat-select option[value='" + vOldVal + "']").attr("disabled", false); }
```

}

Comment: what did you use to substitute for the `ddl` in your JS?

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase that? I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: In your Javascript you have `function cleanUsers(ddl)`.. did you use that as `ddl` or did you substitute something in for it

Comment: The `ddl` identifier is passed in from the dropdown lists when the value changes as `@onchange = "cleanUsers(this);"` within the function I referred to it as ddl e.g. `$("#" + ddl.id).attr("data-selected");`

Does that  answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a local list object `List<MyType> selectedUsers = new List<MyType>();` and as users are selected from the list, you could add them to `selectedUsers`. Compare the `selectedUsers` to the available users and if there is a match, remove the user from the other list. There are most definitely many ways to do this, but this is the one that came to mind first.

Comment: Thanks Ingenious, I managed to find a javascript solution which I've now posted in the original question. This sounds like it could work although I was trying to get the solution working within the view in real time so information didn't have to be posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you have multiple drop-down lists for the same model? I am assuming you're simply trying to select multiple users loaded from the same model. In that case you simply have to use a select list with the multiple attribute.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, Model.UserList, "Select User", new { multiple = "", @class = "form-control", @id = "idP2" })
```

If however you really have to use multiple drop-down lists -- and I'm assuming you want to achieve all these before the form is submitted -- then you'll have to use JavaScript. Maintain a list of all users in a JavaScript array. Each time a user is selected, repopulate the other lists and exclude the selected user. Make sure to check whether a selection has been made in the other lists before repopulating so you don't erase the selection.

Comment: Thanks David, I've managed to put a solution together with Javascript and attributes. I wasn't aware of select lists with multiple which is interesting. 

The reason they are separated is each person needs to be assigned a specific seat and I wasn't positive how to do this without each string being added to the FormCollection in order.

However, that said. I'm sure there is a better way of generating a number of the same drop-down lists without hard coding each (some form of array perhaps). I just haven't yet found/thought of one.

Comment: I still don't see why they need to be in separate lists. Maybe its because I don't yet understand what you're trying to achieve. But if you use a drop-down list with the multiple attribute, they'll arrive as a list object to your controller. You can then simply loop through and assign seat numbers. If you want a fixed number of users to be selected then that's simply a validation you'd have to implement in the front end as well as back end.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The Administrator who will be using this form will want to control exactly which user will be in each seat. In this implementation, each drop-down relates to a specific seat. e.g. Seat one goes to Bertie and Seat 2 goes to Bob. If looping through in the controller, the administrator wouldn't have control over who has which seat as far as I can tell.